# Can not get Stripe recipients to verify through API

Tags: api, payment-gateway, payment-processing, stripe-payments

I am trying to create Stripe recipient objects - but no matter what I try I've never been able to get one to come back as "verified." My understanding is that Stripe verifies recipients by checking the name and EIN / SSN fields against a government database. So far as I call tell I'm entering in valid data that should pass the test.

There are no webhooks for validating a recipient - they are either verified immediately upon creating (or updating) a recipient, or they are not verified at all.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Furthermore ... do I even *need* to verify recipients before making bank transfers? They highly recommend it in the docs - although it's unclear whether it's actually necessary for making a successful transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes us a little while to verify EINs on recipients (SSNs are somewhat faster). In the meantime, feel free to send out transfers to these recipients if you're confident they are who they say they are.

Comment: really? Can you provide a bit more of an explanation or a link to documentation that says that?

Comment: I am going to second ajbraus's request. Do you manually verify each EIN and SSN?